# Hi! How can I do this code better? without all that select. I have found some codes but none of them works for this part End.(xlDown)

Tags: excel, vba, select, offset

Simple copy and paste, this macro takes everything from those columns and paste them in another sheetas values (configurator)

```
Range("A3:B3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Configurator").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I want this macro to be faster by optimizing it with a better code